# Is torch.nn.LSTM equal to tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, lstm

One paper has released a tensorflow code for the classification task. It relies on tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell with default setting.

I try to use PyTorch 1.0 to re-implement, and I use torch.nn.LSTM with default setting. But the testing accuracy is lower than the tensorflow codes.

I check the usage of these two lstm, and I think the default settings are the same. So I am confused...

Comment: I think `torch.nn.LSTM` is equivalent to `tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnLSTM`, not `tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell`. I'm not familiar enough with tensorflow to be certain, but I hope someone else can confirm and post it as an answer.

Comment: @myrtlecat is correct if you are running on a gpu

Comment: @myrtlecat Thanks. Could you please explain a bit more about the difference for CPU.

Comment: @cookiemonster Thanks. Also for  the difference for CPU